# Сделать 2 ресайза подпяд. Битрикс

Tags: битрикс, resize

Загружается оригинальная картинка в свойство "оригинальная картинка". Есть 3 свойства "большой квадрат", "маленький квадрат" и "прямоугольник"

так же есть 3 временных свойства "большой квадрат (временное)", "маленький квадрат (временное)" и "прямоугольник (временное)"

проблема в том, что картинки после второго ресайза добавляются те же самые, что и после первого. размеры одинаковые, хотя пути разные. в чем может быть проблема?

код

```
class AddImage{

function AddImageFunc($arFields){
    $el = new CIBlockElement;
    $element_id = $arFields['ID'];

    // первый ресайз
    $res = CIBlockElement::GetList(
        array('sort'),
        array('ID' => $element_id),
        false,
        false,
        array("ID", "NAME", "PROPERTY_ORIGINAL")
    );

    while($ob = $res->GetNextElement()){
        $arFieldsElement = $ob->GetFields();
    }

    $original_image_id = $arFieldsElement['PROPERTY_ORIGINAL_VALUE'];

    $big_r1 = CFile::ResizeImageGet(
        $original_image_id,
        array('width'=>820, 'height'=>820),
        BX_RESIZE_IMAGE_PROPORTIONAL_ALT,
        true
    );

    $small_r1 = CFile::ResizeImageGet(
        $original_image_id,
        array('width'=>410, 'height'=>410),
        BX_RESIZE_IMAGE_PROPORTIONAL_ALT,
        true
    );

    $rectangle_r1 = CFile::ResizeImageGet(
        $original_image_id,
        array('width'=>820, 'height'=>410),
        BX_RESIZE_IMAGE_PROPORTIONAL_ALT,
        true
    );

    $big_file_array = CFile::MakeFileArray($big_r1['src']);
    $small_file_array = CFile::MakeFileArray($small_r1['src']);
    $rectangle_file_array = CFile::MakeFileArray($rectangle_r1['src']);

    $PROP = array(
        'BIG_TIME' => array("n0" => $big_file_array),
        'SMALL_TIME' => array("n0" => $small_file_array),
        'RECTANGLE_TIME' => array("n0" => $rectangle_file_array)
    );


    $el->Update($element_id, array('PROPERTY_VALUES' => $PROP));

    // второй ресайз
    $res = CIBlockElement::GetList(
        array('sort'),
        array('ID' => $element_id),
        false,
        false,
        array("ID", "NAME", "PROPERTY_BIG_TIME", "PROPERTY_SMALL_TIME", "PROPERTY_RECTANGLE_TIME")
    );

    while($ob = $res->GetNextElement()){
        $arFieldsElement = $ob->GetFields();
    }

    $big_image_id = $arFieldsElement['PROPERTY_BIG_TIME_VALUE'];
    $small_image_id = $arFieldsElement['PROPERTY_SMALL_TIME_VALUE'];
    $recangle_image_id = $arFieldsElement['PROPERTY_RECTANGLE_TIME_VALUE'];

    $big_r2 = CFile::ResizeImageGet(
        $big_image_id,
        array('width'=>820, 'height'=>820),
        BX_RESIZE_IMAGE_EXACT,
        true
    );


    $small_r2 = CFile::ResizeImageGet(
        $small_image_id,
        array('width'=>410, 'height'=>410),
        BX_RESIZE_IMAGE_EXACT,
        true
    );

    $rectangle_r2 = CFile::ResizeImageGet(
        $recangle_image_id,
        array('width'=>820, 'height'=>410),
        BX_RESIZE_IMAGE_EXACT,
        true
    );

    $big_file_array2 = CFile::MakeFileArray($big_r2['src']);
    $small_file_array2 = CFile::MakeFileArray($small_r2['src']);
    $rectangle_file_array2 = CFile::MakeFileArray($rectangle_r2['src']);

    $PROP2 = array(
        'BIG' => array("n0" => $big_file_array2),
        'SMALL' => array("n0" => $small_file_array2),
        'RECTANGLE' => array("n0" => $rectangle_file_array2)
    );

    $el->Update($element_id, array('PROPERTY_VALUES' => $PROP2));
}
```

}